# What would petrification feel like?

Tags: biology, magic

If a character in my book series gets petrified by magic, how would the process feel physically? Here are some things to note when answering this:

-The character has similar physiology to that of a human

-The petrification process takes approximately 5 seconds to complete

-The character loses consciousness as soon as they are 100% petrified

-The petrification is undone later via magic

-The character is not simply being frozen in place but is literally being turned to stone

-The petrification happens as a result of magic

Comment: *"In the very beginning of our renunciation, it is certainly with labour and grief that we practise the virtues. But when we have made progress in them, we no longer feel  sorrow,  or we feel little  sorrow. But as soon as our mortal mind is consumed, and mastered by our alacrity, we practise them with all joy and eagerness, with love and with divine fire."* (Saint [John Climacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Climacus), *Climax, or the [Ladder of Divine Ascent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ladder_of_Divine_Ascent)*, 1:16, trans. Archimandrite Lazarus Moore, Harper & Brothers, 1959)

Comment: Actually , there is an illness called [fibrodysplasia ossificans progressiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibrodysplasia_ossificans_progressiva) with symptoms similar to petrification. You can get a good sense of what happens by reviewing the related case studies.

Comment: The victim will keep thinking they cannot live without you by their side. It passes after spending so many nights thinking how you did them wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything opinion based about this question at all.  It is asking for a description of the physical sensation that would be felt by a human analogue as a result of a specific chemical change in the tissues of that human analogue's body.  The speed with which the process takes place, and the reason it takes place, are handwavium/magic, but that doesn't change that the question and answer have a distinct one-to-one relationship without any opinion involved at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Similar to some kinds of convulsion, everyone put under petrification would let go a loud and horrible scream as all the air is forced outside his body due to intense contraction of muscles or them becoming stone.

The sensation of heaviness of limbs, upper and lower, could be similar to the ones experienced by diabetic people who suffer from peripheral neuropathy. First the sensation of wearing thick gloves and socks, then, as the condition furthers, the lack of feeling with the remaining heaviness.

As the diaphragms gets immobilized, accessory muscle of the chest start to try and balance the inspiration. Visible muscle of the neck and thorax contract painfully until they too get petrified.

Shortness of breath takes place until you just stop breathing, you gasp uncontrollably seconds before you cease any pulmonary activity.

Your muscles may tear, as you're desperate to do something, anything, and keep fighting and moving. Newly transformed fibers might get shredded by soon to be stone muscles that are still functioning.

Your ear's drums just stop moving so you loose your hearing just before losing consciousness, being thrown to a world without any sound.

As your eyes become petrified you feel that scratch and the urge to close your eyelids, but you just can't.

Before you know it, you're out and everything stops. There might be pain involved or not, that's up to you, but clearly desperation would be a part of it. As you get depetrified, you come back to the last thought you had, feeling pain, out of breath and everything. You may not have any damage to you physical body, but your mind might be psychologically damaged and the fear lingers on as you try to understand what just happened.

Comment: This sounds.... terrifying and incredibly painful.

Comment: You might also, briefly, experience [phantom limb pain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_limb).

Answer (score 2):

This answer will focus on the sensation of petrification. After all, the question asks what would petrification feel like.

If petrification only takes five seconds and the petrified person loses consciousness after the conversion into stone. Frankly five seconds isn't much time to respond or react to the process. It would be like undergoing paralysis, being turned into stone make any movement difficult, with rapidly impaired circulation of the blood accompanied by loss of sensation. Large sections of the person's nervous system would be turned to stone. This means any neural signalling would be shut down within seconds.

This makes it very likely the person being petrified will undergo a numbing sensation to their whole body to the extent of a total loss of awareness of their body. Five seconds after its commencement, they will have lost consciousness.

In conclusion, being petrified will feel like fainting or blacking out. There won't be amount time for the failure of their physiological functions to cause any discomfort or pain, becoming immobilized within a very short time (less than five seconds), and followed by a complete loss of consciousness.